# Why is there an “as”?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> There is also a great bitterness which was caused by the centuries of European insolent domination in Asia. This ought to be dealt with by a combination of patient tact with dramatic announcements renouncing such relics of white domination as survive in Asia.

I don’t know what does the *renouncing such relics of white domination as survive in Asia* part mean, can anyone help me with the last line? Why does the author put an as there? It kind of confused me. In what way should I divide the sentence as to understand it better?

Comment: Source please!!

Comment: It’s quoted from Russell’s Why I am not a Communist

Answer (score 1):

"as" is a relative conjunction, it marks a relative clause.  The usual relative conjunction is "that", and you could paraphrase as "… such relics of white domination that survive in Asia." The relative clause describes the relics.

This use is dated, perhaps archaic, except in dialect.

Answer (score 1):

[M-W defines this as a pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as):

> : a fact that
> // is a foreigner, *as* is evident from his accent

In this case, it functions much like the relative pronouns "which" and "that". Here are examples from two recent articles:

> **As** befits a show about a lawyer interacting within the MCU, there are plenty of cameos and inside baseball riffs. ([Scott Mendelson, "‘She-Hulk’ Review: Marvel Finally Makes An Actual Television Show," Forbes, 17 August 2022](https://www.forbes.com/sites/scottmendelson/2022/08/17/she-hulk-review-marvel-finally-makes-an-actual-television-show/?sh=2f5fe3763e31))

> The side feels refreshed and re-energized and if, **as** appears likely, Luciano Spalletti manages to bring in Keylor Navas between the sticks (he's down on Alex Meret for some reason), another top-four finish, and maybe even a little more, could be on the cards. ([Gab Marcotti, "Ansu Fati fabulous for Barcelona, Man City stressed by Newcastle, Leeds humble Chelsea, PSG magic, more," ESPN, 22 August 2022](https://www.espn.com/soccer/blog-marcottis-musings/story/4727361/ansu-fati-fabulous-for-barcelonaman-city-stressed-by-newcastleleeds-humble-chelseapsg-magicmore))

Note that in these sentences the "as" clauses, unlike other relative clauses, precede their referents.

In your sentence, the meaning would similar to "that":

> This ought to be dealt with by a combination of patient tact with dramatic announcements renouncing such relics of white domination **that** survive in Asia.